# Firebase Data from Shared Preferences

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, sharedpreferences

So I have this app which has two screens - Login and Profile.
I fetch data from firebase with the following code:

```
static Map? userData;


//Login Button onPressed
getUserContent() async {
                           await fireStore.collection("SomeCollection").doc(uid)
                              .get()
                              .then((value) {
                            setState(()  {
                              userData = (value.data()!);
                            });
                          });
                        }
```

Then I save this data to shared preferences so that when the user reopens the app they wont have to login again and the data fetched from firebase will be stored on the Profile screen.

```
//Set Data to SP Function
String someString = LoginScreenState.userData!['Name'].toString();
SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
prefs.setString('someStringKey', someString);

//Get Data from SP Function
spString = prefs.getString('someStringKey')!;
```

Then I call both these functions on the Profile Screen's init state.
But if I login it gives me a LateInitializationError as the string from Shared Preferences is null.

I'm new to flutter, any kind of help would be appreciated.

Comment: If you debug the value of `LoginScreenState.userData!['Name']` what return? i think the problem is there

Comment: @MiguelEscobarCalderon I printed its value and it returns the correct value.

Comment: and if you get the value saved in preferences just after call `setString` you get the correct value? Maybe the problem is with preferences

Comment: @MiguelEscobarCalderon I only get the `LateInitializatoinError` for the first time when I login. If I hot restart after the first time it works fine.

Comment: @TittyMcTwister, LateInitializatoinError gives you the hint, that you are using the userData before actually initialising it. 

Ensure you wait until userData is ready and available to for use before continuing.

A good & common practice in this scenario is to have middleware, which ensures the screen you are accessing user is logged in. 

```
Future<GetNavConfig?> redirectDelegate(GetNavConfig route) async {
    if (!FirebaseAuthSer.to.isLoggedInValue) {
      return GetNavConfig.fromRoute(Routes.LOGIN);
    }
    return await super.redirectDelegate(route);
  }
```